# Appending results of two tables in SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to append the results of two tables in oracle SQL. In which single row of one table should repeat to the number of rows of the other table.

example:

**TABLE 1.**

**R_ID  R_name**

654 ABC

364 BCD

541 REA

980 HTD

788 UJS

**TABLE 2.**

**G_ID  G_NAME**

675464  CHEF

**Result**

**G_ID  G_NAME  R_ID    R_name**

675464  CHEF    654     ABC

675464  CHEF    364     BCD

675464  CHEF    541     REA

675464  CHEF    980     HTD

675464  CHEF    788     UJS

I used **union all** but couldn't get the expected result.

Comment: Look up "cross product" or "cross join".

Comment: Actually I meant "Cartesian product". Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UNION alone without ALL?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it myself. This may be helpful for someone.

Union/ Union All wont work in this scenario.

The right way to do this is

**Select * from (Query1, Query2);**

Query1 -retrieves data from table2(one with single row)

Query2 -retrieves data from table1